# Rails Administrate - How to Customize Navigation Link Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate

In administrate if I have a model called parentequipmenttype how to I customize the Navigation link to display as "Parent Equipment Type" instead of listing as parentequipmenttype?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to customize `app/dashboards/parentequipmenttype_dashboard.rb` file.

```rb
require "administrate/custom_dashboard"

class ParentequipmenttypeDashboard < Administrate::CustomDashboard
  resource "Parent Equipment Type"
end
```